# Is the AJAX-style form option no longer available in Gravity Forms v1.8.4?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

The title pretty much sums it up....

... I updated my WordPress installation's plugins, and I am now running Gravity Forms v1.8.4...

... But I cannot seem to find the option anywhere in the settings for creating a form that is AJAX-style, despite plenty of documentation and forum comments on gravityhelp.com stating that one CAN indeed create an AJAX-style form (so long as you do not use re-CAPTCHA, which I do not)...

... So... What gives? Was the option/feature done away with in the new release?...

Answer (score 5):

AJAX is an option you can enable when using the 'add form' modal on the post/page editor, you can also edit an existing shortcode to enable AJAX like so

```
[gravityform id="1" ajax="true"]
```

If you are using the function call to embed the form in a template it could look like this:

```
gravity_form(1, false, false, false, '', true);
```

There are more examples on the following page of the documentation: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Embedding_A_Form